# When a solution of the Sylvester equation is not singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, sylvester-equation

For the matrix equation $AP + PB + C = 0$ we know that there exists a unique solution $P$ if and only if there are no common eigenvalues of $A$ and $-B$ (assuming that $C\ne 0$). But do we know when this solution is invertible?